# Accessing and using Firestore subcollection data using VueJS (rookie question)

Tags: vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

I am fairly new to VueJs and Firestore and I am having a couple of rookie teething problems that I can't quite answer using the documentation. I apologise in advance if this is answered elsewhere, I have been trawling for the last couple of days and couldn't see anything that was directly helpful.

---

So my problem is two-fold:

1) How do I access subcollections in Firestore? - I read that this functionality is now available and I believe you can dive into these subcollections using db.collectionGroup queries however I haven't had much luck using this method.

2) Using the data in VueJs - I am trying to start simple and use this data to populate a basic 'ingredients' table. Assuming I can grab the data from these subcollections, how do I navigate to them? I have been using the v-for method so far.

---

Firebase Structure so far:

I have set up my Firestore with this structure:

https://i.imgur.com/Kijb7GC

'recipes' is the root collection. Inside this I have a document (an individual recipe) which has an author and recipe title field. It also has an ingredients subcollection which is structured as follows:

https://i.imgur.com/YuE3FWk

Each document inside the ingredients subcollection is a key value pair with one ingredient and it's corresponding quantity. The idea is to have a list of different ingredients for each recipe.

---

My Vue code:

I have set up a quick table which looks like:

https://i.imgur.com/HfYP9kz

which results in this awful looking thing:

https://i.imgur.com/aO2gUtH

Hopefully you can see that in the first half of the table code I am able to pull out the recipe title and author and populate the first table row. I need to quickly apologise and mention that the image of my table was taken before I attempted to put in the {{recipe.ingredients.ingredient}}. Anyway..

What I don't know how to do is to dip into the subcollections part and grab the ingredients and quantities to populate the subsequent rows (I had a rookie stab at it...)

At the moment this is the code that is grabbing the recipe collection data:

https://i.imgur.com/BzuYjzp

I am assuming that this is only grabbing the 'surface' level data i.e the author and recipe title but isn't pulling through the subcollection data too.

If you are still with me - great!

What I am trying to understand is:

a) If possible, how do I grab the subcollection data using the db.collection technique?

b) How can I access this data in the v-for method?

Any help is much appreciated. Its a bit of learning curve and I don't have any one I can hassle in the real world!

Comment: Hey Michael, welcome! First off please try and post code, you can use ``` (triple backticks) and it will look nice, this makes it easier to answer you questions. 
In terms of what is coming back the first step would be to find out exactly what is coming back. Put a `console.log(snapshot)` inside your created method and see if you are missing data.
in terms of the way it looks that just means you need to style it...
Lastly I would recommend putting a `v-if` on your whole component `<div v-if="recipes"...`

Comment: Apologies - I knew I would run afoul somewhere but duly noted for next time. I will have an investigation and see what data is being returned. Thanks!

Comment: np, if you find my comment at all helpful please upvote.

Comment: I keep forgetting about logging things to the console. So I took your advice and added a `console.log(doc.data)` and was able to see that I was picking up the data properly. I had another go at the `db.collectionGroup` method using the added console line and could see that I was able to reach into the subcollection! I need to do some more experimentation but its a big step forward for me. Thanks!

(Also unless I missing something, I can't upvote your comment as I am brand new starter..?)