# How to get show a firebase subcollection in a component vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuetify.js

I don't find the way to get a subcollection from firestore, but i can with a field.

I have something wrong in the code of my component, is not connected well with the firestore.

```
<template>
...
 <div v-if="coda"
            :key= "coda.cid"
            :nom="coda.cli.nom"
            :pedT="coda.pedT"
             >
```

here is the field from the firebase document's collection that shows well

```
              <v-toolbar-title >
                <h1> {{coda.cli.nom}} </h1>
              </v-toolbar>
```

here is the subcollection of the same firebase document, but is not working

```
                         <v-data-table
                            :items="pedT"
                            class="elevation-1"
                            >
                            <template v-slot:items="props">
                                <td>{{ props.item.prod.nam }}</td>
                                <td class="text-xs-right">
                                  {{ props.item.prod.uni }}
                                </td>
                          </v-data-table>
...
 </div>
</template>
```

here is the most important code of my script

```
<script>
import { db } from '@/firebase'

export default {
    data: () => ({
         codas: [],
         coda: {
            cli: { nom: '',
                       clid: ''
                     },
            pedT: ''
        },        
        pedT: [],
        pedI: {
            prod: '',            
        },
    })
     methods: {
        abrirCoda(coda) {    
            this.coda = coda;
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

The firestore structure:

```
Usuarios/{uid}/
(Collection)codas/{cid} (coda)/
                              -cid
                              -cli:{
                                   -nom:
                                   -id:
                                   }
                              (subcollection) pedT/{piid} (pedI)/
                                                                -prod: {
                                                                       -nam:
                                                                       -uni:
                                                                        }
```

Comment: Hi @llogaran, Is there a chance for you to share the Firestore structure? This could be helpful to take a look depeer. In addition, I found [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56358372/accessing-and-using-firestore-subcollection-data-using-vuejs-rookie-question) about Using Firestore subcollections with VueJS. There you can find an example about this.

Comment: @BraulioBaron i just add the structure of my firestore. Also I'm working with the by default rules, do I need to do some changes for to get the subcollections?